# Clone doesn't work using ssh key and passphrase?

Tags: java, ssh, clone, jgit, passphrase

I'm trying to clone my repository using ssh key and passphrase, but I always got this problem (SEE BELOW). 
After setting my passphrase to empty, the problem was solved, but I need it with pass. Could you please help me ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
enter code here 
try {


    SshSessionFactory sshSessionFactory = new JschConfigSessionFactory() {
           @Override
            protected void configure(Host hc, Session session)

            {
                session.setPassword("MyPass");
            }
        };
        CloneCommand cloneCommand = Git.cloneRepository();
        cloneCommand.setDirectory(workingDir);
        cloneCommand.setURI("git@.....");
        cloneCommand.setTransportConfigCallback(new TransportConfigCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void configure(Transport transport)
            {
                SshTransport sshTransport = (SshTransport) transport;
                sshTransport.setSshSessionFactory(sshSessionFactory);
            }
        });
        cloneCommand.call();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[Stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1gAN.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full stack trace properly formatted.

Comment: It seems that your SSH key was created without a passphrase.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain the text of the stacktrace. Don't use images of text.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I will edit it. I can't clone in git bash without it. It is not empty.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't edit it.
@RüdigerHerrmann Do you have any other ideas ?